# any way to loop iteration with same item in python?

Tags: python, iterator

It's a common programming task to loop iteration while not receiving next item. For example:

```
for sLine in oFile :
  if ... some logic ... :
    sLine = oFile.next()
    ... some more logic ...
    # at this point i want to continue iteration but without
    # getting next item from oFile. How can this be done in python?
```

Comment: -1: This is baffling.  Perhaps you want a "GOTO"?  Or perhaps you need to define some functions that you can reuse to avoid this contrived looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a simple, deterministic [finite state machine](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-python-state.html). Something like this...

```
state = 1
for sLine in oFile:
   if state == 1:
      if ... some logic ... :
         state = 2
   elif state == 2:
      if ... some logic ... :
         state = 1
```

Comment: no other ways in python? state machine is a good choice, but needs a bit more code :(

Comment: I may be missing something.  How does this help the user put an object back on the front of his iterable for re-consumption?

Comment: Putting an object back isn't the problem. Putting an object back is a solution to a problem. It's just not a good solution. If it was, then programming languages would provide a way to handle it easily. From a CE perspective, FSM is a better solution.

Answer (score 3):

I first thought you wanted the `continue` keyword, but that would of course get you the next line of input.

I think I'm stumped. When looping over the lines of a file, what exactly should happen if you continued the loop without getting a new line?

Do you want to inspect the line again? If so, I suggest adding an inner loop that runs until you're "done" with the input line, which you can then `break` out of, or use maybe the `while`-condition and a flag variable to terminate.

Comment: +1: I was rather stumped too by how someone could expect a file iterator to go on to the next iteration without reading the next line :-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply create an iterator of your own that lets you push data back on the front of the stream so that you can give the loop a line that you want to see over again:

```
next_lines = []
def prependIterator(i):
    while True:
        if next_lines:
            yield(next_lines.pop())
        else:
            yield(i.next())

for sLine in prependIterator(oFile):
    if ... some logic ... :
        sLine = oFile.next()
        ... some more logic ...
        # put the line back so that it gets read
        # again as we head back up to the "for
        # statement
        next_lines.append(sLine)
```

If the prepend_list is never touched, then the prependIterator behaves exactly like whatever iterator it is passed: the if statement inside will always get False and it will just yield up everything in the iterator it has been passed.  But if items are placed on the prepend_list at any point during the iteration, then those will be yielded first instead before it returns back to reading from the main iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through the file line by line, you can do a file.readlines() into a list.  Then loop through the list (which allows you to look at the next item if you want).  Example:

```
list = oFile.readlines()
for i in range(len(list))
    #your stuff
    list[i] #current line
    list[i-1] #previous line
    list[i+1] #next line
```

you can go to the previous or next line by simply using [i-1] or [i+1].  You just need to make sure that no matter what, i does not go out of range.

Comment: is it a way to move one element backwards while iterating list via for in in list ? In text parsing it's a common task if you accumulate lines until you find a line that NOT fits and you need to check this line again

Comment: @eye of hell: if you have a particular use case in mind, please update the question with the description of what you are trying to accomplish in that use case.

Comment: note that even if you use this method i will still be reset to the next number, so you'd also need to remove the next entry from the list (which is expensive).

Comment: @eye of hell: if instead of using a for loop you use a while loop and manually increment or decrement the index as you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Ugly. Wrap the body in another loop.

```
for sLine in oFile :
  while 1:
    if ... some logic ... :
      sLine = oFile.next()
      ... some more logic ...
      continue
    ... some more logic ...
    break
```

A little better:

```
class pushback_iter(object):
    def __init__(self,iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.buffer = []
    def next(self):
        if self.buffer:
            return self.buffer.pop()
        else:
            return self.iterator.next()
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def push(self,item):
        self.buffer.append(item)

it_file = pushback_iter(file)
for sLine in it_file:
    if ... some logic ... :
        sLine = it_file.next()
        ... some more logic ...
        it_file.push(sLine)
        continue
    ... some more logic ...
```

Unfortunately no simple way of referencing the current iterator.

Comment: This looks like a decent solution — not as compact as the suggestion I made about using a generator, but, still, something that uses the same logic, and one of the very few answers here that actually solves the questioner's problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can assign your iterator to an variable then use the .next get te next one.

```
iter = oFile.xreadlines() # is this the correct iterator you want?
try:
  sLine = iter.next()
  while True:
    if ... some logic ... :
      sLine = iter.next()
      ... some more logic ...
      continue
    sLine = iter.next()
except StopIterator:
  pass
```

Comment: readlines() isn't an iterator. It returns a list, and lists don't have a 'next()' property.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to create a variable out of your iterator, and then manipulate that:

```
% cat /tmp/alt-lines.py 
#! /usr/bin/python -tt

import sys

lines = iter(open(sys.argv[1]))
for line in lines:
    print line,
    lines.next()

% cat /tmp/test
1
2
3
4
% /tmp/alt-lines.py /tmp/test
1
3
```

...note that in this case we unconditionally do lines.next() so the above fails for files with odd lines, but I assume that isn't going to be the case for you (and adding the error checking is fairly trivial -- just catch and throw away StopIteration on the manual .next()).

Answer (score -2):

jle's approach should work, though you might as well use enumerate():

```
for linenr, line in enumerate(oFile):
    # your stuff
```